# Complex MuleSoft Cron Schedule

Tags: cron, mule

I'm trying to schedule an app to run every 5 minutes, M-F from 6am-6pm, and every 2 hours, M-F from 6pm-6am. The fixed poll frequency doesn't allow this level of scheduling, so I'm trying to use a cron scheduler.

I set the time zone to `America/Chicago` and the 5M expression to `0 0/5 6-18 ? * 2-6`, and I set the 2H expression to `0 0/120 18-23,0-6 ? * 2-6`.

According to both Cron documentation and MuleSoft documentation, this should be setup correctly and should work, and it does work locally. When I publish this to our VPC (US-EAST), I found that the 2H scheduler was working during the day until about 4PM (Central time), so I changed the expressions to this:

5M `0 0/5 0-12 ? * 2-6`

2H `0 0/120 12-23 ? * 2-6`

Now my 5M scheduler started at 2:15AM and ran until 7AM.

How can I setup two central timezone cron schedules to run 6am-6pm M-F every 5 minutes and 6pm-6am M-F every 2 hours on a VPC server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MuleSoft confirmed to me that their VPC servers are UTC based, regardless of waht time zone you place on the cron scheduler/poll connector. While not ideal, that means that I needed to back the schedulers up 6 hours (to get them to central time). I suspect that DST will cause the schedule to shift one direction by an hour.

[This](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/tutorials/crontrigger.html) is a good resource for learning about Mule Quartz/Cron scheduler.
There is also a [Free Online](https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html) cron scheduler formatter.

For the purpose of my scheduling needs, I ended up needing a total of four cron schedulers

`0 0/5 12-23 ? * 2-6` - runs M-F, 6am-5:55pm (central) every five minutes.

`0 0 0-11/2 ? * 3-6` - runs T-F UTC, but actually runs 6pm-4am M-F every two hours. You only need to run the app up to 4am since it is every two hours, and the five minute schedule will start promptly at 6am. Two things to note here. First, to properly rune very two hours you need to do `/2` on the hour slot, instead of `/120` on the minute. The minute slot can only handle values from 0-59. Second, the days are set to start on Tuesday because of the 6 hour difference from UTC to Central. If you were to use hours 0-11 (UTC) on Monday, the app would actually start at 6pm on Sunday central time.

This brings us to the two additional schedules, one to capture 12am-4am on Monday (central), and a second to capture 6pm-12am on Friday (central).

`0 0 6-11/2 ? * 2` - runs every two hours between 12am-4am (central) on Monday.

`0 0 0-6/2 ? * 7` - runs every two hours between 6pm and 12am (central) on Friday.